# Making a combined file name from several drop down lists

Tags: string

I am trying to figure out how to use Excel, or some other means, to create a name generator. So for example, you choose (from a drop down list I pre-define) several attributes then it spits out a name I can then copy and paste when saving my file.

For example:
I select Room 25, on floor 11, of building A in Orlando campus, it would spit out:

ORL-A-1125

Is this something excel is capable of? If not, can anyone recommend an alternative application or approach and how to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is possible in Excel. You need to arrange your list entries in columns and the shorter codes they translate to in an adjacent column. You need a pair of columns for each section.

Choose a cell for the dropdown and right click it. Go to Data | Validation | Allow | List. This lets you define the range of cells that the dropdown gets it's entries from. Do that for each of your four sections.

Beneath each dropdown you then need to use the "VLOOKUP" function that looks up the value your dropdown has selected and returns the value 1 column to the right.

Finally write a formula to concatenate the four sections into a single string and you've got your filename.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-drop-down-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1